# Swift integrate pattern MVC and Facade pattern

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am very confused and would like to have your suggestion about using a powerful architecture.
1) First question
The pattern I am using are mvc end Facade.
In my project all controllers called the Facade class. The facade class calls the Model (business logic)
This process is considered performance from your experiences?
2) Second question
The manual of the Facade pattern suggests using a single class centralized.
Here I go crazy :)
Imagine having a class (A) which contains 20 methods, and a class (B) which contains 20 other methods.
The Facade class instantiates class (A) end class (B)
I'll have to call in the Facade class call 40 methods?
Become a class very very big :(

From your experience what system you have adopted?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is your actual question? :) Are you asking about how to implement those specific patterns in swift for iOS or what?

Comment: Yes exactly. How do I build the facade pattern in Swift?
I have a class (A) inside contains 20 methods. Class (B) contains within 20 methods. How to implement the pattern facade?

Answer (score 3):

Before you go into "how do I implement it", you should really think about why to implement it.

**Facade design pattern**

The Facade pattern is used to make your life easier by creating simpler interface for otherwise complex system. Usually - as you already probably noticed, you use it for management of multiple classes (or even subsystems that you have interface for).

What it means in practice is that you will use facade pattern everywhere where you are doing tasks regularly with the same boilerplate code (which is quite often) so those can be replaced with something shorter or if the facade will provide you with cleaner code that is simpler to manage. Also, you can use it to shield internal implementation, so if some subsystem changes they way how they work, your higher-level function will still remain the same and fill the same role.

**How to build facade**

There are some [great examples on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), I suggest you to read through them, especially code example of simple computer. I used it as example for Swift version:

```
// --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
// MARK: - Definitions

private let BOOT_ADDRESS = 0


// --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
// MARK: - Subsystems

class CPU {

    func freeze() { }
    func jump(position : Int64) { }
    func execute() { }
}


class Memory {

    func load(position : Int64, data : NSData) { }
}


class HardDrive {

    func read(position : Int64, data : NSData) -> NSData { }
}


// --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
// MARK: - Facade

class Computer {

    // Create all computer subsystems
    let cpu = CPU()
    let memory = Memory()
    let hdd = HardDrive()

    // Implement reason why you are creating this facade
    func start() {

        self.cpu.freeze()
        self.memory.load(BOOT_ADDRESS, data: NSData())
        self.cpu.jump(BOOT_ADDRESS)
        self.cpu.execute()
    }
}
```

Now as you can see, you have CPU, Memory and HDD, all complicated stuff internally. But you only care about facade - Computer. This allows you to start computer without thinking about how to do it, like this:

```
// Create computer object
let computer = Computer()

// Start computer (how is it done is none of your bussiness)
computer.start()
```

Now how you do it for your particular problem is up to you, but you should follow similar thinking. And don't forget, that you should only use Facade if it actually helps you. Never try to use it just because you know what it is (because it happens quite often that people overuse those patterns and then end up with terrible code).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help
Use the facade pattern for an entire project I think is wrong.
Because the main class Es .. (RootFacade) would count many classes and methods very much.
I think I use this pattern only for complicated processes that call many classes. Example (call webservice).

Comment: Facade is only support pattern. For building to iOS app, you should follow standard MVC pattern as recommended by Apple. You can read about it more on Apple website: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html